# UIImageView outlet is still nil after viewDidLoad only on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, iboutlet

I have an static UITableView with grouped cells, and an outlet for an UIImageView in the first group and I try to set its image on viewDidLoad like this

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
          [super viewDidLoad];
          self.productImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"];
    }
```

I found the productImageView (UIImageView) is nil but only on iOS7 (7.1.2), as far as I knew, it shouldn't be nil *after* viewDidLoad

Can anyone tell me why this is the only outlet is not loading from my storyboard?

Comment: did you linked your outlet?

Comment: yes, it is, it works on iOS8

Answer (score 0):

Moving your code to the viewWillAppear will likely fix your issue, but that's not really the optimal solution. What if you add a call to `[self.tableView reloadData];` before you set the image to make sure that the tableView is initialized?

Comment: I've tried moving it to viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, now I can tell this UIImageView is not even instantiated because does not even show the background color, the cell seems like empty

Comment: Yeah something weird must be going on. If you put a breakpoint in viewWillAppear and the do "po self.productImageView" does it say that productImageView is nil?

Comment: Yes, even after the view was completely loaded the UIImageView was nil, but I found the reason :D thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the reason

I made the ViewController in a different storyboard, Xcode 6, with the new format for storyboards and different devices, but actually, our project is as old as Xcode 5 and we still use those storyboards, when I made *copy & paste* of the ViewController from the new storyboard to the old one, it should work because we are used to this, and it does with iOS8, but I noticed the view is shown like this in the view inspector

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ticT5.png (can't post images yet)

Seems like the image and its constraints are disabled and deleting the element, adding a new one seems to solve the problem for iOS7 and still work with iOS8